# There is gap in MaterialUI AppBar

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

This is my first time using Material UI (or front end world) for react. It went good actually, but I notice there is white gap in my header.

[image]

And here is my index.js that loads MuiTheme:

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    textColor: teal500,
  },
});

render(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Is there a styling I need to apply?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add `body { margin: 0; }` to your CSS.

Comment: sorry, that one was my fault. You are right. This issue is similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716654/how-to-make-an-appbar-component-fill-all-divs-width-and-10-of-its-height?rq=1